# New Language Keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard

Hope you all had a great festive season!

It is possible to write a different keyboard with spell check and everything and have it work with the globe button..?

In South Africa we have 11 official languages and English is the only one on iOS by default..

Does someone have literature on this..?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

API allow you to add keys to existing keyboard and even to replace it completely, but is limited to the app you developed. There's no way to register a "global" keyboard available to other apps.

Comment: Ok I see.. But what if I want to have an entire different keyboard. Something that will give you the option of a different language all together in Settings - general - keyboard - keyboard - (then selecting a language that iOS doesn't cater for)..?

Comment: Almost like the way Emoji used to work.. Download the app from app store and install..

Comment: It's different: that app simply add an already existing keyboard, it don't create a new one...